# Calculating Distance Between Dates Only If Range Criterion Met

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table of data containing people and two sets of dates like so:

[image]

Notice that Date2 for John falls within the range of the dates in the Date1 column while this is not the case for Tim.  What I would like to be able to do is calculate the difference between each Date1 and Date2 only if Date2 is between the minimum and maximum dates for the person in question.  In this example John's date difference would be calculated and Tim's would not.  Since this would be happening for multiple different people the formula or macro would need to have some way of knowing when the name changes in order to determine both the minimum and maximum dates.  I am not sure if this is feasible to complete using a formula, but that was my initial approach.  Should I be attempting to make a macro instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following code in cell `D2`

```
{=IF(AND(MIN(IF(A:A=A2,B:B))<=C2,MAX(IF(A:A=A2,B:B))>=C2),B2-C2,"")}
```

End the formula by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and drag the cell down along the side of your table.

This formula will calculate the differences between `Date1` and `Date2` only if `Date2` is in-between the range of `Date1` for each person.